# no debug information available

Tags: macos, gcc, gdb

I'm using Mac OS 10.7.4. I've installed Xcode and updated gcc up to 4.6.3 using port command.

And now in my working directory (~/Work/[project]/work/build) I use dbg and get hundreds of lines like:

warning: Could not find object file "/Volumes/work/macports/var/macports/build/_Volumes_work_mports_dports_lang_gcc46/gcc46/work/build/x86_64-apple-darwin11/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/bitmap_allocator.o" - no debug information available for "../../../../gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++-v3/src/bitmap_allocator.cc".

What can be a problem and hot to fix it?